# Create seperate dataframe from column items of dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

i have a dataframe which looks like this [players dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWGwH.png). i want to make seperate dataframe for each club name
for eg:

```
real_madrid=fifa[fifa['club']=='Real Madrid']
arsenal=fifa[fifa['club']=='Arsenal']
```

for every possible club present in dataset, how can i do so?

Comment: fifa.groupby('club) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# generator
clubs = df.groupby('club')
clubs = (clubs.get_group(group) for group in clubs.groups)
clubs.__next__()
# or a list
clubs = [clubs.get_group(group) for group in clubs.groups]
clubs[0]
```

Or you could do a loop if you don't want a generator or list of dataframes

Comment: this is highly inefficient, you'll redo the `groupby` every time

Comment: Noted.  Adjusted the code accordingly.